# Can this jq map be simplified?

Tags: json, jq

Given this JSON:

```
{
  "key": "/books/OL1000072M",
  "source_records": [
    "ia:daywithtroubadou00pern",
    "bwb:9780822519157",
    "marc:marc_loc_2016/BooksAll.2016.part25.utf8:103836014:1267"
  ]
}
```

Can the following `jq` code be simplified?

```
jq -r '.key as $olid | .source_records | map([$olid, .])[] | @tsv'
```

The use of variable assignment feels like cheating and I'm wondering if it can be eliminated. The goal is to map the `key` value onto each of the `source_records` values and output a two column TSV.

Comment: I think the use of variable assignment can make script faster. For example, `jq -r '.key as $olid | .source_records[] | [$olid, .] | @tsv'` is 15% faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of mapping into an array, and then iterating over it (`map(…)[]`) just create an array and collect its items (`[…]`). Also, you can get rid of the variable binding (`as`) by moving the second part into its own context using parens.

```bash
jq -r '[.key] + (.source_records[] | [.]) | @tsv'
```

---

Alternatively, instead of using `@tsv` you could build your tab-separated output string yourself. Either by concatenation (`… + …`) or by string interpolation (`"\(…)"`):

```bash
jq -r '.key + "\t" + .source_records[]'
```

```bash
jq -r '"\(.key)\t\(.source_records[])"'
```

---

Output:

```
/books/OL1000072M   ia:daywithtroubadou00pern
/books/OL1000072M   bwb:9780822519157
/books/OL1000072M   marc:marc_loc_2016/BooksAll.2016.part25.utf8:103836014:1267
```

Comment: If the goal is to produce TSV, it is preferable to use `@tsv` as it provides robustness, e.g. in the case that there are embedded tabs or newline characters in the values. It also provides clarity about intention.

Answer (score 1):

It's not much shorter, but I think it's clearer than the original and clearer than the other shorter answers.

```bash
jq -r '.key as $olid | .source_records[] | [ $olid, . ] | @tsv'
```